# How to import an existing AWS WAF ACL into terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-waf

I am trying to import a few AWS WAF ACLs into an existing terraform deployment. I have tried both variations of the code.

```
#version 1:

resource "aws_waf_web_acl" "mywaf" {
  # (resource arguments)
}

$ terraform import aws_waf_web_acl.mywaf id-xxxx-xxx
```

> Error: aws_waf_web_acl.mywaf (import id: xxxx-xxx): 1 error(s) occurred
>   Terraform detected a resource with this ID doesn't
>   exist. Please verify the ID is correct.

```
#version 2:

resource "aws_wafregional_web_acl" "mywaf" {
  # (resource arguments)
}

$ terraform import aws_wafregional_web_acl.mywaf id-xxxx-xxx
```

> Error: aws_wafregional_web_acl doesn't support import

I have verified that the ID is correct. Is this possible with AWS provider 1.45? Thanks.

Comment: It turns out you were right regarding incorrect ID. I was able to get that by using the command: ```aws waf --region us-east-1 list-web-acls```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the id is wrong.

From the [sample](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/waf_web_acl.html)

```
terraform import aws_waf_web_acl.main 0c8e583e-18f3-4c13-9e2a-67c4805d2f94
```

it is uuid, not `id-xxx`

And for second resource, it clearly claims that this resource doesn't support import feature currently

reference: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/wafregional_web_acl.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. Sorry, I purposefully obfuscated the ID for security reasons but my original ID does have that form.

Comment: Even with v2.66.0 of the AWS Terraform provider (released 2 days ago) which has support for aws_wafregional_web_acl, an import doesn't work. I get the same error: "ID doesn't exist"

Comment: Aaaand someone has a PR for this: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/9248/files